# How to filter content (admin view) based on taxonomy term

Tags: views

I'm looking for a way (I'm happy to write a module if shown the way) to filter content in the admin view based on taxonomy term. I've been using the [Administration View](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) modules, but it doesn't provide what I'm looking for. And to be honest, I'd be happy to write a simple module that would do such thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Administration Views] https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views you should be able to enable or extend an existing view.  I have done it for content but have had trouble with that module and had to revert a few times.
[image: Views Admin Vocabulary]

Comment: Yes, I'm using this module but it seems it doesn't do what I want it to (I want be able to filter content by taxonomy term on specific post types)

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "post types".  I just installed admin views and it shows "Vocabulary" as a filter (I happen to be useing commerce kickstart but believe this is generally avail.)

Comment: @Sonicthoughts The question is to filter by term of vocabulary, not just by vocabulary